# Layout selector missing

Tags: interface

I was toggling between *layout views* (Default, Animation, etc) and I accidentally got this:

[image: snapshot]

I don't know how to simply restore the "Default" layout... or any layout. Many of the interface elements are gone and I was able to bring back some by clicking "maximize area" in one of the tool bars

So, anyone knows a way of restoring the default layout without using the layout button?
thanks in advance!

(I've tried searching and apparently no-one had this problem before...)

Comment: @invincente What about the "Back to previous" button in the top left corner?

Comment: it serves another purpose, is for enabling/disabling just that toolbar

Comment: Please could you upload your .blend file? Thanks ;)

Comment: If you don't have any work to save, try File>Load factory settings.

Comment: You can use `Ctrl+LeftArrow` and `Ctrl+RightArrow` to switch layouts.

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3, as you can see, I could solve it. But those commands don't seem to do anything in mac. I've tried command+leftArrow and nothing... and Ctrl makes some native stuff.... it would be useful to know the differences thou.

Answer (score 4):

You have toggled the 'current' space (whichever part of the interface the cursor was in) to be full screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or the *Back to previous* button that has appeared in the top toolbar (next to *Render*, *Window*, *Help* etc) to restore the space to it's previous size.

Comment: @invicente Please could you upload your .blend file? Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks!, but it doesn't work. Im afraid because it's a problem with layouts selection. Right before this problem i selected a weird layout named something like "Animation.0001" (this was the complete coment,sorry)

Comment: (how do i upload it?)

Comment: @invicente Are you there?

Comment: In the top left, click on "Stackexchange" and then, next to Blender Stack Exchange, click on chat. Send me a message like this @TimTimmy Hi!

Comment: Once you have done that, upload the .blend file here: http://www.filedropper.com/ (you will be shown a window to choose the .blend file and click OK), once you have done this, wait for it to upload and send me the link via chat. e.g.: @TimTimmy Here is the link: *link*

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be here till tomorrow. ;)

Comment: hey, sory i was uploading and wasn't around. but here's the link if it helps... thank you! https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsabufhef3anzc6/EPRIL.blend

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12219/discussion-between-invicente-and-tim-timmy)

Comment: @invicente Try pressing `Ctrl+DownArrow`

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys I finally solved it:

First i selected "Load Factory Settings" wich started a new normal file.
But at this point, if I was to open the file i was working on, it would load the same way, no menus, no viewports, etc.

So, instead, in the new file, I went to User Preferences/File and unchecked "Load UI".

Then I opened my file and now it loaded normally.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: You don't need to disable *Load UI* in the User prefs, there is a check box in the file browser when you are opening a file. It's under *File Browser > Tool shelf (`N`) > Open Blender file > Load UI*. It should be on the lower right.