# Deleted Game logic layout by accident

Tags: edit-mode

[image]Accidentally deleted game logic layout is there anyway of getting it back?
haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layout selector missing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5887/layout-selector-missing)

Comment: So what I got from that was I need to reload my UI in user preferences? I'm not sure if my problems the same as the one you showed, I've completely deleted game logic layout from the drop down menu at the top nothing else changed, I can still do everything as normal I just don't have the option of game logic, I'm pretty new to blender so i might not be explaining this properly.

Comment: @ProjectMedal Maybe share a screenshot then? What is the expected behavior, what are you seeing/getting? See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe. As it is now, it's not clear what you're asking. Closing as unclear until clarified.

Comment: Can you have another look at it now with the screen shot, might make a bit more sense i hope :S

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I was looking for thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 menu below that looks like icons with 2 arrows. In your screenshot  there are icons like "cube" (which is view port where you can see your objects, scene and anything you are working on) and "clock".

If you don't use the clock just click on it and choose *Logic Editor*, and then after all set up you can save this view as  "game logic" - just rename it from "default". So as we see even we accidentally delete any of menus we can add it by yourself

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. [**Please add images**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) of what you mean by [**editing**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136851/edit) your answer. You can do this by using the edit link below your question. That would help us a lot to understand your answer.